# crystal reports 2008 convert string to date time (SQL)

Tags: sql, string, date, crystal-reports, varchar

Good day; Recently our software developer made a change to the time and date tables, which resulted in these fields being separated and changed to a `string` format. Now none of my time formulas will display. I emailed them for help and they sent me a SQL expression that looks like this:

```
CAST   (
    CONVERT(Varchar(10), ATCC_Contacted, 112) + ' ' +   
    CONVERT(Varchar(8), ATCC_Contacted_Time) AS DateTime)
```

I have attempted to insert this into the report, but it returns a warning;

> Failed to retrieve data from the database.
>
> Failed to retrieve data from the database.
>        Details: ADO Error Code: 0x
>        Source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server
>        Description: The conversion of a varchar data type to a 
>                     datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
>        SQL State: 22007
>        Native Error: [Database Vendor Code: 242]

I am way out of my depth on this one, and would appreciate any advice given. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to give us some further information, e.g. what the new string format is.

Comment: You should probably also kick your software developer for (1) changing a datetime datatype to a string and (2) not anticipating downstream issues like this.

Comment: Paddy; when I spoke to the rep the other day - all he said was TimeVar. Would that answer the question of what type of string format it is?

Comment: So it looks like maybe they have split it into two fields, one with a 'date' datatype and one with a 'time' datatype.  Don't know why.  If you can confirm this, you can work from there.  Timevar is not a sql server data type - they are listed here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186724.aspx

Comment: I was told that your suspicion is correct. Apparently the two fields were as on, and when a date was auto-filled into our software it would then also default to 00:00:00, and created erroneous time intervals that absolutely wreaked havoc in the reports I run. So, in order to eliminate that issue they were required to separate it into different time and date fields. What I need to do now, is combine them into a format that crystal can understand and can be used to calculate time intervals that sometimes cross the 24 hour mark.

Comment: Also, thank you for that link. I'm anxious to try some of the functions, and hopefully put them into play.